# Getting error after Magento user login

Tags: javascript, magento

I am using Magento ver. 1.9.1.1  . When front-end user logged-in it is giving this js error .

> TypeError: $link.attr(...) is undefined

and few of the functionalities stop working I think the things which are coming through js libraries are getting issue . It is working fine for the anonymous user means no front-end user logged-in .Is there anybody familiar or faced related issue . Can help

Answer (score 1):

All my solutions are based on assumptions as question is not clear.

1] It seems your js conflict with other js. According to me update the jquery above 1.6. It might solve your issue. http://api.jquery.com/attr/

> As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes
>   that have not been set. To retrieve and change DOM properties such as
>   the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the
>   .prop() method.

2] Put `jQuery.noConflict();` at the end of your jquery file.

3] If error occur in your custom js. As you have not posted the file or code in which you get an error. So according to me the attribute you are searching for isn't set on the element you're searching for it on. Due to this,`.replace` is failing because undefined doesn't have a replace method. You'll need to make sure it isn't undefined first.

```
var attribute = $(this).attr('rel'); //Maybe you're getting error here. Change it like this.
attribute = attribute ? attribute.replace('attributeremove_', '') : '';
```

Comment: error coming in jquery.nav.js I used in new theme . I tried with your suggested ways updating jquery to version you asked and also put the jQuery.noConflict(); but no difference . Its working fine for anonymous user . What can be the difference when user logged-in ?